# Spring 5 - HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm doing Website from tutorial and I'm using Spring. Sadly code from video is not working in my IDE.

There is pom.xml.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>Travel</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>Travel</name>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <release>17</release>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  
  
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
  <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  
  
</project>
```

And WebConfing.

```
package main.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.SpringTemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafViewResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("main")
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;
    
    @Bean
    public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver(context.getServletContext());
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return resolver;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        return templateEngine;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        return viewResolver;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

}
```

When I try to put it in localhost i can see error 500 in browser and then this is from IDE:

```
sty 07, 2023 7:36:20 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet [dispatcher]
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
ServletContextTemplateResolver cannot be resolved to a type
ServletContextTemplateResolver cannot be resolved to a type
ServletContextTemplateResolver cannot be resolved to a type
The method getServletContext() from the type WebApplicationContext refers to the missing type ServletContext

at main.config.WebConfig.templateResolver(WebConfig.java:31)
at main.config.WebConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0.CGLIB$templateResolver$1(<generated>)
at main.config.WebConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$2.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:258)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
at main.config.WebConfig$$SpringCGLIB$$0.templateResolver(<generated>)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:491)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1324)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1161)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:915)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:706)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:583)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:537)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:169)
at jakarta.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.init(HttpServlet.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:995)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:696)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:128)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:400)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

So for sure this lines are wrong:

```
    @Bean
    public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver(context.getServletContext());
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return resolver;
    }
```

I tried to change it in this way:

```
    @Bean
    public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver((ServletContext) context.getServletContext());
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return resolver;
    }
```

Still same, 500 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in [the changelogs](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/What%27s-New-in-Spring-Framework-6.x), Spring migrated to Jakarta EE in the 6.0 release.

In your `pom.xml`, you are using version `6.0.3` of `spring-webmvc` (which requires Jakarta EE) but also `javax.servlet-api` which is part of Java EE.

You basically have two options:

### Migrate to Jakarta EE

Replace

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

with

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

This will then use version `6.0.0` of the Jakarta Servlet API instead of version 4.0.1 of the Java EE servlet API.

Alternatively, you can use an older version like `5.0.0`.

Similarly, you would need to [upgrade thymeleaf to 3.1.x as this version supports Spring 6 and Jakarta EE](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/thymeleaf31whatsnew.html).
For doing so, replace

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
  <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

with

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
  <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring6</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

so that Thymeleaf is compatible with your Spring version as well.

Aside from updating dependencies, it is also important to replace the use of `ServletContextTemplateResolver` with something else as [these were changed in Spring 3.1](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/thymeleaf31whatsnew.html).

Since it is a Spring application, you might be able to use `SpringResourceTemplateResolver` as described [in this Tutorial for Thymeleaf 3.1](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.1/thymeleafspring.html#the-springstandard-dialect):

```java
@Bean
public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver(){
    // SpringResourceTemplateResolver automatically integrates with Spring's own
    // resource resolution infrastructure, which is highly recommended.
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setApplicationContext(this.applicationContext);
    templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    // HTML is the default value, added here for the sake of clarity.
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
    // Template cache is true by default. Set to false if you want
    // templates to be automatically updated when modified.
    templateResolver.setCacheable(true);
    return templateResolver;
}
```

Alternatively, you might be able to use [`WebApplicationTemplateResolver`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf/latest/org/thymeleaf/templateresolver/WebApplicationTemplateResolver.html) which can work with both Java EE (using `JavaxServletWebApplication`) and Jakarta EE (using `JakartaServletWebApplication`):

```java
    @Bean
    public WebApplicationTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        WebApplicationTemplateResolver resolver = new WebApplicationTemplateResolver(JakartaServletWebApplication.buildApplication(context.getServletContext()));
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return resolver;
    }
```

### Downgrade Spring

Another possibility is to use a version of Spring Webmvc before `6.x`.
For doing that, replace

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

with

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.24</version>
    </dependency>
```

However, when using 5.x versions of Spring, you would miss the other features of Spring 6.x (including possible future features).

Comment: First of all, thanks for quick respond. So I decided to migrate to Jakarta EE. Sadly ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver(context.getServletContext()); is still red. Can you prove me more details to fix it? Thanks! (It shows: The constructor ServletContextTemplateResolver(ServletContext) refers to the missing type ServletContext).

Comment: Also make sure to change `thymeleaf-spring5` to `thymeleaf-spring6` and update your project in your IDE (Alt+F5 in Eclipse) after that change. In case the error persists, did the error message change in any way?

Comment: So i changed pom.xml thymeleaf-spring6 and jakarta.servlet. Just "new ServletContextTemplateResolver(context.getServletContext());" is red and message shows "The constructor ServletContextTemplateResolver(ServletContext) refers to the missing type ServletContext". I updated all couple of times, even i turned off and on Eclipse. Still not working.

Comment: For Jakarta EE, you need to [update thymeleaf itself to `3.1.x`](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/thymeleaf31whatsnew.html) as well (e.g.`3.1.1-RELEASE`). However, this might result in `ServletContextTemplateResolver` not existing any more. You might be able to use [`SpringResourceTemplateResolver`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring6/latest/org/thymeleaf/spring6/templateresolver/SpringResourceTemplateResolver.html) instead.

Comment: See [this section of the Thymeleaf docs](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.1/thymeleafspring.html#the-springstandard-dialect) on how to use `SpringResourceTemplateResolver`.

Comment: Alternatively, you could create a [`WebApplicationTemplateResolver`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf/latest/org/thymeleaf/templateresolver/WebApplicationTemplateResolver.html) using `new WebApplicationTemplateResolver(JakartaServletWebApplication.buildApplication(context.getServletContext()))`.

Comment: You are awesome! Real legend! It is working! I spend 1.5 days to try to solve it. Thanks. So for future guys. Yes, ServletContextTemplateResolver is not longer working. You have to use SpringResourceTemplateResolver instead.